# Unable to open chromedriver in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver

[image]

I'm facing errors while trying to execute a simple code to launch a chrome browser and open google.com but not able to launch the browser. Attached is the error message.

This is the code -

```
package gmailpkg;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class login {

    public static String driverPath = "X:/JARs-Setup/chromedriver_win32/";
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//*[@href='https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm']")).click();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on how it fails. Crash? Hang? Error message?

Comment: Post the error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: Paste complete error message

Comment: At Console its says - at gmailpkg.login.main(login.java:14), while clicking on it driver = new ChromeDriver(); is getting highlighted. Please provide some solutions

Comment: @AppanSinghaRoy, Please update complete error you facing